# I need help escaping string parameters for a javascript function using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am dynamically creating an anchor that calls a javascript function. It works with one string parameter but not with two. I believe I am not escaping the quotes around the parameters correctly. In search for an answer I came across the following

```
onclick="alert('<?echo $row['username']?>')"
```

and the next one I found left me completely baffled

```
echo('<button type="button" id="button'.$ctr.'"onClick="showMapsInfo(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $maps_name).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $ctr).'\');"><img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>');
```

If someone would please

1. Explain why the single quotes around username do not have to be escaped?
2. Where there is a "dummies" write up on escaping characters so I could try to decipher the second example.

Comment: instead of `str_replace`, use `addslashes` and provide a blank space here: `'"onClick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine your first example

```
onclick="alert('<?echo $row['username']?>')"
```

The important part here is, that everything outside of `<? … ?>` is pure HTML and never looked at by the PHP interpreter. Therefore, the only part that is relevant for PHP is the code inside `<? … ?>`, namely `echo $row['username']`. Here, one does not need to do any escaping.

Your second example, in contrast

```
echo('<button type="button" id="button'.$ctr.'"onClick="showMapsInfo(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $maps_name).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $ctr).'\');"><img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>');
```

is written purely in PHP, no surrounding HTML. Therefore, you have to be careful with the quotes. Let's build this up from scratch to see what happens here. When you build something like this, you would probably start with

```
echo('<button type="button" id="button1" onClick="showMapsInfo(\'...\');"><img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>');
```

Because the single quotes were already used as string delimiters, they must be escaped inside the string with `\'`. Now for the part inside the javascript function. Put even simpler, the above code boils down to

```
echo('showMapsInfo(\'...\');');
```

which results in

```
showMapsInfo('...');
```

when we want to insert some dynamic parts instead of the '...' part, we need to end the string with `'` and concatenate it back together with `.`. Suppose you wanted to insert a variable `$foobar` in there, then you would write:

```
echo('showMapsInfo(\''.$foobar.'\');');
```

which results in

```
showMapsInfo('<VALUE OF $foobar>');
```

Your example does not insert `$foobar` into this string, but rather the following expression:

```
str_replace("'", "\\'", $maps_name).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $ctr)
```

Which uses `str_replace` in order to again escape the content, but with a little twist: It is not escaped for PHP, but for the resulting Javascript! Every single quote `'` becomes an escaped single quote `\'` in the output, but you need to write `\\'` because the backslash needs to be escaped itself, in order to produce a backslash as output.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed reply it has helped considerably.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the quotes and then use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), it is more legible and easier to understand.

```
$maps_name = str_replace("'", "\\'", $maps_name);
$ctr       = str_replace("'", "\\'", $ctr);

echo <<<HTML

<button type="button" id="button$ctr" onClick="showMapsInfo('$maps_name', '$ctr');"><img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>

HTML;
```

Comment: Edited to fix the php.net link to the English version. This is surely more readable, but still requires escaping the `'` inside the php vars otherwise the JS will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Thanks, i forgot to update the link. About the `'`, he can just call `str_replace()` before echo the heredoc, i've made an update.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Thanks! (Valeu! Primeiro brasileiro que encontro por aqui!)

Comment: There are many Brazilians here (even though you don't see them very often), well don't forget to check out the [Stack Overflow in Portuguese proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539) and commit if you didn't already. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_encode` function for the javascript variable.

```
echo sprintf(
  '<button type="button" id="button%s" onClick="showMapsInfo(%s, %s);">
   <img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>',
    htmlspecialchars($ctr), json_encode($maps_name), json_encode($ctr));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but for now json will have to wait I am still struggling with PHP, javascript, CSS and HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

1. The single quotes around username do not have to be escaped because it is part of the PHP variable, not the JavaScript.
2. Information on injecting PHP variables into JavaScript can be found [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/javascript-escape/) and more info [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/).

   You only need to enclose the PHP variables in quotes if the variable is a string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will follow the links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have problem in escaping single quote as the function is working when you are

calling it using one parameter only.

Check if you are creating the whole parameter sting correctly, if the comma is added properly and in javascript if single quote comes around bot the parameters.

finally the parameter string should look like

'param1', 'param2'